# Why is Custom Error Page not working in my nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, config

I have following server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name utsav-dev.domain.org;
    root /var/www/domain-utsav-dev/web;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-utsav-dev-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain-utsav-dev-error.log error;
    error_page 404 = /var/www/domain/web/50x.html;

    set $thttps $https;
    set $tscheme $scheme;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = http) {
      set $thttps off;
      set $tscheme "http";
    }
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = HTTP) {
      set $thttps off;
      set $tscheme "http";
    }



    index app.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app.php/$1;
    }
    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 86400;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION "www";
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV "dev";
    fastcgi_param PDFLIBLICENSEFILE "/etc/php5/fpm/pdflib.license";
        fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $thttps;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
   chunked_transfer_encoding off;

}
```

Now as per script if a page is not found, nginx should internally redirect to 50x.html but when I try to open **http://utsav-dev.domain.org/blah.html** it gives me error **"File Not Found"** than custom 404 page I was expecting. Why?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app.php?r=$1` or `try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite =404;`

Comment: @myninjaname: Would rewrite effect the location of custom error page?

Comment: It look's like it, but with `app.php/$1` and not `?r=$1` (or `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING q=$uri&$args` in @rewrite), you'll get the File Not Found error (which I think is from fastcgi, not nginx, hence why it's not going to 404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` in your fastcgi location.

`fastcgi_intercept_errors on | off;
Determines whether FastCGI server responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.`

when you visit `http://utsav-dev.domain.org/blah.html`:

- first check each location. No one hit
- it go through the `try_files`. Hit the @rewrite location.
- the uri changed to /app.php/blah.html
- hit the fastcgi location.

you should set `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` to let `error_page` work